# Hypothesising no effect

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am testing many things in my investigation and I could also have a side hypothesis about certain relationship. However previous research shows that there is no relationship. Does it make sense to hypothesise no effect? My sample is quite small so it is very likely that I would find support for the "no effect".

Comment: So called equivalence testing can be usefull: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test

Comment: Look at Blackwelder's article on "reversing the null and alternative hypotheses:.